# Factorial in excel without vba and power function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hi I have homework to do in excel and i am stuck. I have to write formulas in excel to calculate factorial of a given number ( i cant use vba or factorial function). I enabled iterative calculations. So far i have something like this

```
=IF(C5<1;"Wrong number!!!";IF(D5<C5;+C5*(C5-D5);1))
```

where C5 is number given by user and D5 is iteration which is set to number one. I wanted to than change D5 to D5+1 and so on but well unfortunately u cannot do that in excel, so how can i fix that or what different approach i can take?

Comment: Ask yourself "what is a factorial?" - answer: the product of a sequence of integers.  Now, if only Excel had functions called [Product](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/product-function-8e6b5b24-90ee-4650-aeec-80982a0512ce) and [Sequence](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sequence-function-57467a98-57e0-4817-9f14-2eb78519ca90)...

Answer (score 0):

Try below formula-

```
=MAX(SCAN(1,SEQUENCE(C5),LAMBDA(x,y,x*y)))
```

[image]

Comment: unfortunately formula doesnt work there is an error

Comment: Then you do not have LAMBDA function. What is your excel version?

Comment: my version is 2206